# python lambda for list_of_list collapse

Tags: python, list, lambda

OK, newbie getting in knots with a list_of_list collapse.

I already figured out that I can reduce the for loops below to the comprehension.

```
lol = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54], \
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54], \
       [150, 151, 152, 153, 154]]

collapsed_lol = list()
for innerlist in lol:
    for item in innerlist:
        collapsed_lol.append(item)

collapsed_lol = [item for innerlist in lol for item in innerlist]
```

But then I tried a reduce(lambda) approach and got unstuck. Why does this not work?

```
collapsed_lol = reduce(lambda a,x: a.extend(x), lol)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'
# lol
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54], [50, 51, 52, 53, 54], [150, 151, 152, 153, 154]] 
# so lol[0].append[lol[1]] did occur, but then stopped.
```

If I assign the lambda to a variable instead of inside reduce, it does the same, successfully doing lol[0].extend[lol[1]]; the return is None.

```
f = lambda a,b: a.extend(b)
lst_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lst_2 = [50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
ret=f(lst_1,lst_2)
ret # is nothing
lst_1
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
lst_2
# [50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
print f(lst_1,lst_2)
# None
```

This is the same behavior as in the nested reduce contruct.

Clearly I'm trying something that doesn't work, not the way lambda's are supposed to be used - but can someone explain what the None represents, what the process involved here is? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you pass to reduce has to return the value of `fn(a,b)`. Since `extend()` returns None, then you can't use the lambda that you have.

You *can* force the lambda to return the value by changing it to:

```
fn = lambda a,b: a.extend(b) or a
```

and calling `reduce(fn, lol)` will return the value of all the lists in 'lol' appended together. Note though what happens. You will also have modified the first element of `lol` to be this summed value. Why? Because the first call to `reduce()` uses the first 2 elements of the given sequence for `a` and `b`, calls `fn(a,b)`, and uses that returned value as the `a` for the next call, and the next element in the list for `b`, and so on until the list is exhausted. If it were written in Python it would look something like:

```
def reduce(fn, seq):
    seq_iter = iter(seq)
    a = next(seq_iter)
    for b in seq_iter:
        a = fn(a,b)
    return a
```

Since `extend()` updates the list in place, you will repeatedly extend that `lol[0]` element.

You may be better off just using `sum(lol, [])` to flatten your list-of-lists. It has some memory warts relative to making many copies of intermediate lists, but for short lists like this it is very simple and gets the job done.

If you are absolutely set on using `reduce` and don't want to modify the contents of `lol`, just use `reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, lol)`. This will also generate the many intermediate lists, but it won't modify the contents of `lol` (because when `a` and `b` are lists, `a+b` returns a new list, it doesn't modify in place like `extend()`).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'm just getting started so this kind of contribution is really great. I'm not so much absolutely set on 'using reduce' as learning.

Answer (score 0):

that's just a function that's return `None`.

```
f = lambda a,b: a.extend(b)
```

This function **only** modify `a`.
And it's the same than:

```
def fct(a, b):
    return a.extend(b)
```